# Basis for a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let the space of polynomials of $x$ of degree $\leq n-1$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{K}$.

How can I show that $\{1, x-a, (x-a)^2, \cdots, (x-a)^{n-1}\}$ form a basis for this linear space?

I try write $(x-a)^n$ using the binomial theorem and use the fact of $\{1, x, x^2, \cdots, x^{n-1}\}$ is a basis, but it is not working.

P.S.: I would like to show this using the fact that a base is a linearly independent set that generates the whole space, without results very "distant" from this definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if you know that the dimension of the vector space is $n$ (you already have your other basis), then it suffices to show that your set spans the vector space since your set has size $n$. For this, it suffices to show that each of $1, x, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ can be written as linear combinations of elements in your set. For example, $x$ can be written as $(x-a)+a \cdot 1$.

Comment: Showing that the set spans the space is not enough: one has to show that it's linearly independent, too.

Comment: @rudy not if there's $n$ of them in an $n-$dimensional space.

Comment: @DavidP Tru dat. I will not delete my comment though as I think it might be useful to others who read this thread.

Comment: Use mathematical induction and it worked, thank you.